# Titanium : View click event not working after flip left animation

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am new to titanium and I was just checking with view animations maybe I did not get the concept right but here's my code which I have tried so far

```
MainFunctions.someTestMethod = function(sender){

    var cardDetailsView = Titanium.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor:"red",
        name:"cardDetails",
    });
    var  cardImageView = Titanium.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor:"pink",
        name:"cardImage",
    });

    var containerView = Titanium.UI.createView();
    containerView.backgroundColor="green";

    var cardAnimation = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
    cardAnimation.view=cardDetailsView;
    cardAnimation.transition= Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT;
    cardAnimation.duration=2500;

    //cardImageView.animate({opacity:1,duration:2000,});
    //cardImageView.animate(cardAnimation);

    //Click event for when you press the card view you will see the card info page
    cardImageView.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        Ti.API.log("card back event called");
        cardImageView.animate({
            view : cardDetailsView,
            opacity:1,
            transition : Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT,
            duration : 500
        }); 
    });

    cardDetailsView.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        Ti.API.log("cardDetailsView event called");
        cardDetailsView.animate({
            view : cardImageView,
            opacity:1,
            transition : Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT,
            duration : 500
        }); 
    });

    containerView.add(cardImageView);
    containerView.add(cardDetailsView);
    cardWindow.add(containerView);
};
```

In the console I get this as a warning

```
[WARN] :   New layout set while view [object TiUIView] animating: Will relayout after animation.
```

The problem that I am stuck here is with the flip animations, what happens is when I click on cardImageView it flips and displays the cardDetailsView but when I tap on the cardDetailsView it does not flip to show me the cardImageView and the application crashes.

Can you please help me out what is the detect the issue here I am not really sure what's stopping this, I even tried to crack the kitchen sink demo but still no luck.

Please help me to detect the issue,
Thanks.

Comment: Could you add some logs which are printed when the app crashes? In Titanium they are not always useful but maybe they can provide important hints.

Comment: Hello @RobinEllerkmann i do not see any crash logs but i do see warnings which i have added in my question, please have a look and let me know what needs to be done.

Comment: But you have several Ti.API.log commands in your code which could help you to locate the problem. For example when you click on the cardDetailView, does it show the Ti.API.log("cardDetailsView event called"); command?

Comment: @RobinEllerkmann: As of now i am doing that and i am able to see the logs but its not helping much